# How to asign well numerical values efficiently before to plot?

Tags: plotting, evaluation, variable

A problem is presented  when the substitution of the numerical values for this function

```
Uz = (-(1/4) - I/4) (2 Sqrt[\[Pi]])/k  1/Sqrt[k R]      E^(-((2 I a n \[Pi])/\[CapitalLambda])   - (n^2 \[Pi]^2)/( b^2 \[CapitalLambda]^2) - (I (k^2 R^2 + (n \[Pi] + k z)^2))/(2  k R)) (Erfi[((1/2 + I/2) (n \[Pi] + k (-R + z)))/Sqrt[k R]] - Erfi[((1/2 + I/2) (n \[Pi] + k (R + z)))/Sqrt[k R]] + 
    Erfi[((1/2 + I/2) (k R - Sqrt[D^2 k^2 + (n \[Pi] + k z)^2]))/Sqrt[k R]] + Erfi[((1/2 + I/2) (k R + Sqrt[D^2 k^2 + (n \[Pi] + k z)^2]))/Sqrt[k R]])
```

I used

```
valplot = { k R -> 1, z -> 1,  b -> 1, z -> 0, \[CapitalLambda] -> 1 }

Ux1 = Uz /. valplot
```

Please, observe that I have a variable kR and sqrt of kR. It is possible to evaluate with a unique value?
It is possible to do the parameter independently. Another detail is when a  product of parameters is presented. How can it is possible to fix it, this point is important for future plot analysis.

Answer (score 1):

It would certainly be easier to specify the values of the variables independently. They appear together in the expression in several different ways.

`Uz // FullForm` reveals the underlying expression. Looking for the products of `k` and `R`, we find

```
Times[Complex[0, Rational[-1, 2]], Power[k, -1], Power[R, -1], 
 Plus[Times[Power[k, 2], Power[R, 2]]
```

and

```
Power[Times[k, R], Rational[-1, 2]]
```

The underlying expression of your replacement rule `k R -> 1` is `FullForm[k R -> 1]` which gives `Rule[Times[k,R],1]`. This works on `Power[Times[k, R], Rational[-1, 2]]` because there the product between `k` and `R` is the same as on the LHS of the rule, but it doesn't work for the other ones, such as `Times[Power[k, 2], Power[R, 2]]`, because the LHS of the rule does not match this expression.

One solution is the following:

```
valplot = {k R -> 1, k^-1 R^-1 -> 1, k^2 R^2 -> 1, z -> 1, b -> 1, 
   z -> 0, \[CapitalLambda] -> 1};
Ux1 = Uz //. valplot
```

`//.` must be used instead of `/.` because `/.` will only do one replacement per expression, and your expression has two products of `k` and `R` in the same which need to be replaced. `//.` will do that by applying the rules repeatedly until nothing changes.

You can also write the rules as

```
valplot = {k R -> 1, Power[k, x_] Power[R, x_] -> 1, z -> 1, b -> 1, 
   z -> 0, \[CapitalLambda] -> 1};
```

This will replace the both `k^-1 R^-1` and `k^2 R^2` using a single rule.